# Magento 1.9 Show Newest Products in Footer

Tags: php, html, css, magento, e-commerce

EDIT: It turns out that the solution below was in fact the correct one. It turns out that my vagrant box didn't have php5-gd installed and so magento was failing to do image stuff, but PHP wasn't showing an error to say it wasn't installed. So make sure you install php5-gd :P

Good day!

I'm currently working on a Magento 1.9 based e-commerce website and I'm basically picking it up as I go along. I am currently taking a static design and turing it into a Magento theme.

I'm trying to show images (with links) to the 6 newest products in the store in the footer area of the store, but the tutorials and questions I have found haven't worked for me.

I have basically taken my footer from the static template and pasted it into my themes footer.phtml file. The design calls for the six images to be displayed like this in the html (if that makes sense?)

```
<div class="medium-6 large-3 columns newlyAdded">
    <div class="footerHat"></div>
    <h3> Newly Added</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
            <li><img src="./images/footer-image-1.jpg" alt="footer image"></li>
            <li><img src="./images/footer-image-2.jpg" alt="footer image"></li>
            <li><img src="./images/footer-image-3.jpg" alt="footer image"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
            <li><img src="./images/footer-image-4.jpg" alt="footer image"></li>
            <li><img src="./images/footer-image-5.jpg" alt="footer image"></li>
            <li><img src="./images/footer-image-6.jpg" alt="footer image"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My initial thought was to stick this into a static block and then loop over some stuff from a model in Magento, but I'm not sure if that is the best way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and of course I will provide as much information as I can :)

Thanks

**EDIT: Extra Info**

footer related stuff in the page.xml file:

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
        <label>Page Footer</label>
        <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
    </block>
    <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
    <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
</block>

<block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
    <label>Page Bottom</label>
    <block type="page/html_cookieNotice" name="global_cookie_notice" as ="global_cookie_notice" template="page/html/cookienotice.phtml" before="-" />
</block>

<reference name="footer">
    <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml">
        <action method="setProductsCount"><count>4</count></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

footer.phtml file (default magento version)

```
<div class="footer-container">
    <div class="footer">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
        <p class="bugs"><?php echo $this->__('Help Us to Keep Magento Healthy') ?> - <a href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking" onclick="this.target='_blank'"><strong><?php echo $this->__('Report All Bugs') ?></strong></a> <?php echo $this->__('(ver. %s)', Mage::getVersion()) ?></p>
        <address><?php echo $this->getCopyright() ?></address>
    </div>
</div>
```

the custom_page.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <custom_layout translate="label">
        <label>Custom layout</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/custom_layout.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </custom_layout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento already has this functionality you can use the following code to display the new products in footer/whichever location you want to display

```
<reference name="footer">
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
<action method="setProductsCount"><count>4</count></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

**NOTE** That I'm considering you have followed Magento's way of theming and have "reference footer" if you want you can put the block code inside any reference call and may call it directly in your footer.phtml.

If you want to style the layout create a copy of "app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/new.phtml" in "app/design/frontend/{themepackage}/{themename}/template/catalog/product/new.phtml" and modify the layout.

Feel free to comment if you have any doubts! Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Dharam, thanks for the super quick reply. From what I am aware I am using the reference way of theming the footer (copied the footer.phtml from the default template).

When I try to do this however it makes the footer disappear, I tried it in a reference block and in the default page/html_footer block in page.xml and I get the same result.

Would it help if I posted the footer.phtml file and some other files?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you remove that [after="cms_page"] from the code and try once also in index.php of your Magento root add the following for debugging purpose

    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Hi. I tried that and I still get the same result, the footer disappears and I don't get any errors. Is there any more information I could provide that would help? Thanks

Comment: Yes, please provide your footer.phtml file and local.xml file for you theme where you have kept the block code. HEY BTW - You must make sure that you have few products where their "NEW Date" is set correctly.

Comment: I think I have some progress on this. I pulled back in the old footer and added that XML and the new products are showing. It must be that I am missing some call to something in Magento theme. I'll keep looking around and post my findings for others. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, as I have just tested it in my new Magento instance and it is working. If you finally get it to work upvote the answer and accept it if it has really helped you. Thanks Buddy! Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi Dharam, thanks I will most certainly upvote and mark it as the answer :). I am actually experiencing something a little weird. When I add the reference block it seems to completely overwrite the footer and just places the product_new block there. I'm going to add to the question the xml for this footer section as well as the current contents of the phtml file (just the default magento).

Comment: Where and how you have added it, I might be able to help! :)

Comment: Hi, I've just added it to the bottom of the question :) I hope that is the information you wanted, if not I'll try my best to find the stuff you wanted :)

Comment: It looks good and it should work, can you try putting it in <block type="page/html_footer" and see.

Worst case scenario you can do the following

<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml">
        <action method="setProductsCount"><count>4</count></action>
    </block>

Have that code declared directly not inside any reference rather as an individual block and call that block in your footer.phtml

Comment: Just to let you know that, I have set it up and have exactly what you have. And it is working fine for me. No disturbance to the footer. Are yuo doing it in your local system or have an URL where we can see this??

Comment: Thanks. I've just added that block into the page/html_footer. You mention calling it directly from the footer.phtml, how would I do that? I've tried <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog/product_new'); ?> and a few other variations but they didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Hi, I am doing this on my local system with a vagrant box. I forgot that I should mention. I have a custom_page.xml as well for the home page, but this same effect is happening on all of the pages, and that custom_page is getting the footer from the page.xml from what I can tell.

Comment: I will add the custom_page.xml to the question

Comment: `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_new'); ?>` OR `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('home.catalog.product.new'); ?>`

Comment: Hi Dharam. I just tried that and nothing changes. It would appear the the products_new is just completely overriding the footer and is only displaying what it is in that products/new.phtml template. Is there any reason you can think of why this may be happening?

Comment: Nothing from the top of my head. I think this needs some debugging from your end. It should work like that. Try to comment that echo and see whats happening. It is a strange error. BTW- I would suggest to try in Magento's default theme, just to check if it is anything to do with your custom theme.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help. I will try this tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: Hi Dharam, thanks for all of the help. It would seem that even in the default theme the footer is getting completely overwritten, which is a bit strange. I have had a thought of using a static block to insert the new products template, I've got the static block in the correct place but I haven't found a good way of inserting the template into the static block. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Hi Dharam. My coworker managed to solve it, so I will post the solution soon for others to see.